# How to set an UIImageView's image property from initWithCode for a custom Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I do this?

It works perfectly, if I set it like this:

```
if(indexPath.row == lastSelectedCell) {
    // last cell
    TWMainViewExpandedCell *cell = (TWMainViewExpandedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExpandedCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = (TWMainViewExpandedCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainViewExpandedCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        _circleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

However, when trying to set the same image property from here (this is a sub class of a UITableViewCell, btw):

```
@implementation TWMainViewExpandedCell

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"initWithCoder");

    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _circleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This last one doesn't work. Why? I do know initWithCoder is being called.

Comment: Where is the outlet `_circleImage` declared?

Comment: Corresponding *.h file =) fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `circleImage` outlet is not yet connected when `initWithCoder:` is called, so it's still `nil`. Do this in `awakeFromNib`.